# Xcode - Unable to install library via pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying an example of SocketRocket and have installed the library using "pod install" that return "Integrating client project". But, building the project, it fails with the message:

```
> diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory diff:
> /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory error: The sandbox is not in
> sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods
> installation.
```

In the directoty are present the Podfile and the Podfile.lock.

Podfile is:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, "7.0"

pod "SocketRocket"
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Update/Install your cocoapods. If it is not getting installed better install Ruby & then install cocoapods. Create a file(Podfile) in TextMate without any extension & save it in the project where you want to install cocoapods. Then drag & drop the path & install the pod file by using the command pod Install in terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly try to update cocoapods.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, provide your `Podfile`.
It should be at the same directory where your `*.xcodeproj` placed.
Have you checked [Cocoapods Tutorial](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html)?

Comment: check this answer then
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072396/cocoapods-errors-on-project-build