# <Restkit/Restkit.h> not found in Xcode6

Tags: ios, xcode6, restkit

I have rest kit integrated into my project. I am getting above error while I try to archive in xcode6. This problem doesn’t exists when I archive in Xcode 5. So,it is definitely a problem with new xcode6. Does anyone faced this issue ? How to rectify that?

Comment: What header search paths are defined for your debug and release configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Following link helped me to resolve the problem. Removed workspace file & ran pod install again.
Hope it helps you!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131855/3564064