# "Duplicate interface definition" suddenly happening on archiving and using cocoa pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Made some changes to a project today, but when I went to archive it for release I suddenly get a duplicate interface definition for one of the pods. It built just fine a few days ago, and builds and runs just fine on the simulator, but once I try to archive it throws up the error.

It's complaining about duplicate interface definition for the "Pop" pod. It's not a static library as far as I can tell (which the Cocoapods page lists as a cause for this problem), so what might be wrong here?

I've tried to clean the build folder, but it doesn't seem to help. I haven't changed anything in the pod, just in my own project. The duplicate definitions it's complaining about is from the header file in the pod, and from the header file in Cocoapods Headers/Build folder.

Comment: Could we have the linker logs ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any log messages here other than the duplicate interface definition in the Issue Navigator.

Comment: If you clic on it you don't have a huge Linker trace ?

Comment: No. Here's a screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/3B343E1c0P31

Comment: Then Pop is already included somewhere in your project I guess !

Comment: But it's not! At least I can't see it anywhere else.

Comment: Can you search for PopAnimation in your workspace finder ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81289/discussion-between-christian-a-strommen-and-quentin-hayot).

Comment: Delete the workspace and create it again

Comment: If the error happens only in Release, you might want to check your Project settings for Release and Scheme. You can also have a look at your podfile, podfile.xcconfig in order to check if you don't have specific configurations for release or debug. You can also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072396/cocoapods-errors-on-project-build and eventually redo a git clone of your project and a "pod install" after updating pod

Comment: Did u get solution for this? I am facing same issue.