# The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock-ios

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podfile-lock

I have got the following errors after trying multiple answers from the google.

```
PhaseScriptExecution Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/FoodSpot.build/Debug-
    iphonesimulator/FoodSpotTests.build/Script-36819C3C1B6A30F50091382D.sh
        cd "/Users/apple/Downloads/FoodSpot 2"
        /bin/sh -c /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/FoodSpot.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FoodSpotTests.build/Script-36819C3C1B6A30F50091382D.sh

    diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
    diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
    error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. 
    Run 'pod   install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I have updated and installed many times, but they are of no use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Run 'pod   install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

**You have answer in the error itself !**

The error message states that you should update your [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) installation.

You could remove libPods  in frameworks and libraries and update Cocoapods using `pod install`.

**Also:**

clean and build the project

**SO references :**

[CocoaPods Errors on Project Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072396/cocoapods-errors-on-project-build)

[Error:"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock..." after installing RestKit with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res)

Comment: clean and build the project

Comment: For future seekers:  Clean and build are both located under the "Product" tab of the main menu.

Answer (score 46):

For me, the reason was missign User-Defined variables in the Build Settings!

Looking into the issue, the Build Phases tries to diff 2 files.

```
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
```

Just because of missing PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH and PODS_ROOT variables, assumes them as "" so ${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock points to /Podfile.lock and same for the other one.
So it fails in

`diff /Podfile.lock and /Manifest.lock`

I fixed this by adding 2 User-Defined settings to the Build Settings

```
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
```

After hours of searching this is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: This is the proper solution to the problem.

Comment: This was my situation also. I found that "pod deintegrate" and then running "pod install" added these settings back in for me so that I didn't need to set these myself explicitly.

Comment: I tried before with different solutions but this one is the most accurate.
I tried the other solutions I was doing without understanding but now I understand.

Comment: 'PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods' isn't a valid name for a build setting. The first character should be a letter or an underscore, and the remaining characters should be letters, underscores, or numbers.
I am receiving this error though I think its a valid name

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: Where do I set "User-Defined variables" in the "Build Settings" ?
I have no such group under my Build Settings in Xcode (12.5).

Comment: That is not true - I do have a "User-Defined " section - I just can't use the Search at the top of Build Settings to find it for some reason.  So to get to User-Defined I scroll to the bottom of Build Settings - OR, I can use the little + button at the top to add a new one.  Unfortunately this doesn't fully fix my build as I'm now facing "Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h' file not found"

Answer (score 33):

For me, it works after the following:

```
pod deintegrate --verbose    
pod install --verbose
```

Answer (score 15):

I had been searching for hours and I found solutions as follow:

In my case, method 3 works.

**Method 1:**

1. choose the target > go to **Build Phrases** > click **Link Binary With Libraries** > remove all **libPods.a** files
2. open Terminal > direct to your project > run:

   ```
    pod install
   ```
3. clean and build project

[ref.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738557/10717246)

**Method 2:**

1. open Terminal > direct to your project > run:

   ```
   pod deintegrate --verbose    
   pod install --verbose
   ```

[ref.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35446801/10717246)

**Method 3:**

1. choose the target > go to **Build Settings** > click "+" sign
2. add 2 User-Defined Settings: [to the left = to the right]

   ```
   PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
   ```

   and

   ```
   PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/
   ```

[ref.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107769/10717246)

Answer (score 5):

Just go to Build phases and click on [CP]check Pods Manifest.lock.

```
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
```

Both PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH and POD_ROOT should define in user-Defined in build settings. 
POD_ROOT should have correct path to Manifext.lock file and
POD_PODFILE_DIR_PATH should have correct path for Podfile.lock

So Add below in build settings.

```
PODS_ROOT ---- ${SRCROOT}/Pods

PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH ---- ${SRCROOT}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is Podfile.lock and Manifest.lock cannot be found by the Check Pods Manifest.lock Script in your targets build phase.

[image]

This is usually caused by PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH and PODS_ROOT variables not being defined.

Go to build settings tab to define them.

[image]

You will need to look for Podfile.lock and Manifest.lock in your project and get the the full paths of their directories. The directory paths will be the values you use for PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH and PODS_ROOT.

Comment: Yes, I got the same issue it got fixed by ur answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

It turned out my issue was due to a new line at the end of the Manifest.lock that was not present in the PodFile.lock file.  Running a diff on the two files highlighted the issue.

Adding a new line to the end of the PodFile.lock file solved it.

**Original Answer**

None of the answers have worked for me so I have just checked the "For install builds only" under "[CP] Check Pods Manifest. lock" which is found in the build phases tab.

I believe this setting means it will only run that check when archiving, allowing me to continue developing as I don't need to archive the app on my machine.

Use with caution though as it may not be the best solution for everyone.

[image: [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock]

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the derived data did the trick for me . I deleted by going into the finder itself.

Answer (score 2):

Make changes in the podfile as given below:

**Older pod file**

target  :TargetName,  :exclusive  =>  true  do

**Changed pod file**

target  'TargetName'  do

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you have opened your Projects' workspace which you try to install new Pods. So try out the following (for me this worked):

1. Clean the project
2. Close the project
3. Run `pod install`
4. Open the project and try re-building it once more

Problem might have been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add a "pod install" command line build step, before the `Xcode Project` build step.

The error is coming from the build phase run script in your Xcode project's target, which is unable to find Podfile.lock. This file is generated by CocoaPods, which must be installed in a build step in your TeamCity project.

My build steps look like:

1. Command line: `bundle install --path .bundle` (installs cocoapods local to the project using `Gemfile`).
2. Command line: `bundle exec pod install --verbose` (uses `Podfile`)
3. Command line: `carthage update --platform iOS` (uses `Cartfile`)
4. Xcode Project
5. Command line to build an archive
6. Command line to upload a build

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got same error after integrating my other targets. To solve problem I needed to add both targets in Podfile:

```
abstract_target 'myApp' do
   use_frameworks!

   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'

    target 'myAppOtherTarget'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens if cocoa pods don't install or uninstall properly

If you want to install cocoa pods run

```
pod install
```

if you you want to uninstall cocoa pods then run command

```
pod deintegrate
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out the cocoapods version on Manifest.lock was higher than what I had on my mac. I had to do a 'sudo gem install cocoapods', to get the version of the cocoapods upto what was specified on the Manifest.lock file. This fixed the issue and I had no errors on building the project.

Answer (score 1):

Im facing the same issue now and fixed using this command after navigating to project location in terminal.

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding 2 User-Defined settings to the Build Settings

```
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the errors were occurring on a _Tests target. I didn't need the _Tests target, and so I deleted it. This resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to move your Podfile like i did and face this issue, the solution discussed below may help -

1. Delete all of the following - Pods folder, xcworkspace
   file, podlock file (skip the ones that are not available for subfolders)
2. delete all steps that has [cp] in it from the build phase tab
3. repeat step 1 & 2 for all the sub projects that you have in your workspace
4. open workspace, go into each project and delete framework for pods, and delete the pods folder from each project
5. close workspace
6. run pod install

you should now be able to open, build and run the project

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by updating the Cocoapod, cause before the error there was log where the warning shows we need to upgrade our cocoapods as the pod files are not supported by the current cocoapod version, So clean the project , upgrade cocoapod then install pod.

```
1. Clean project
2. sudo gem install cocoapods/gem install cocoapods
3. pod install (optional if your project still shows error)
```

Note: I found this error for my flutter application in iOS platform

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use your old project pod folder in your current project, you have to copy `Manifest.lock` file of your current project and replace that file in your old project's pod folder which you added. `Manifest.lock` file location YourProject->Pods->Manifest.lock
Hope This was helpful. worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Top Sites - Sandbox Sync iOS](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52617228.shtml) for more explanation. I fixed the issue by changing file paths from

`diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null`

to

`diff "${SRCROOT}/Podfile.lock" "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null`

in `Xocde -> "Open Your Project" -> "Select Your Project" -> "Select Your Target" -> Build Phases -> Check Pods Manifest.lock`

If not, try changing paths as mentioned above, along with `Legacy Build System`. To change build system `Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System -> Legacy Build System`

Answer (score -1):

I hate to say this, but I just removed the pods/ or didn't include them in the project and it built. I don't know if this will have a long-term effect on the project though.

This is presently my .sh build script for ionic5 for ios. It will probably change in the future.

```
# BUILDING FOR IOS

##################################
#
#     MAKE SURE YOU UNPLUG ALL DEVICES!!!!!
#
##################################

 
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova prepare ios 
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --verbose
cd platforms
cd ios
open "MyApp.xcworkspace/"
cd ..
cd ..
```

It had be plaguing my project, so I thought I'd take them out. I am yet to deploy the project so far though... so who knows.
BigSur 11.1, XCode 12.4 (12D4e)