# Cocoapods Errors : Resource.sh not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, cocoapods, apptentive

Folks,

> Cocoapods : 0.39.0

FYI I have done enough research and I was able to take care of errors like:

> Podfile.lock not found.
>
> .menifest not found

and others while building my project.

Which still seem hack to me but as long as they let me build I dont care. 
But one real problem is this :

**Pod-resources.sh not found and this one is in the pod directory.**

so for sure Its not in my source control as I dont check in pods dir into my project. 
I have done more than enough weokspace deletion, podlock deletion, who pods dir deletion and pod install. but this problem is still there. 
**I am using apptentive which has a resource bundle,** which need to be copied to the app binary.

At the moment I have disable Apptentive thru out the project to speed up the development and keep looking for solution.

Links that I have read are follows :

> https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2303
>   is from July 10, 2014 : seem too old to rely on.
>
> [CocoaPods Errors on Project Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072396/cocoapods-errors-on-project-build)
>
> [Error:"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock..." after installing RestKit with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res)
>
> [The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738339/the-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-ios)
>
> [Error:"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock..." after installing RestKit with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res)

```
How I solved my partial problem : delete workspace file, Pods Dir and .lock file. If this can help anybody.
```

Comment: Can you do a pod install --verbose and paste in the output?

Answer (score 1):

Culprit was the path. It seem how Cocoapods is handling is different than earlier. 
What it dont do is updating your project file for Copy Resources phase:
it seems they have update the path and now it has "/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/" in it.

> Older path:  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Pods-ProjectName-resources.sh"
>
> New Path:  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-projectName/Pods-Project-resources.sh"

So if you are having same errors like me you need to do is :

> - remove workspace file
> - remove .podlock file
> - remove .menifest file
> - **do Pod install**
> - update the path in build phase in xcode project file as shown above.
> - Now Build the project/workspace

Hope this will save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add a PODS_ROOT user-defined build setting, as described [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2627#issuecomment-61742414).

Comment: I think problem is resource.sh file is not being generated. Not the issue with the PODS_ROOT. But you comment was very helpful to find  the root cause. I really appreciate it.