# Pods not found after creating new schemes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've just decided to create a couple of different schemes with different configurations. However it get "No such module 'podname'", when I try to build it.

I've followed [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/managing-different-environments-and-configurations-for-ios-projects-7970327dd9c9) guide, and tried to build just before the steps where you add configuration files. Any ideas why my pods doesn't get recognised? The new schemes I've created is name "development", "test" and "production".

This is how my podfile looks like:

[image]

When I run Pod install, I get the following messages:

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `10.0` on target `NoteIt` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `NoteIt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (development).xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (development).xcconfig` in your build configuration (`NoteIt/Development.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `NoteIt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (test).xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (test).xcconfig` in your build configuration (`NoteIt/Test.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `NoteIt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (production).xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (production).xcconfig` in your build configuration (`NoteIt/Production.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `NoteIt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(development).xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(development).xcconfig` in your build configuration (`NoteIt/Development.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `NoteIt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(test).xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(test).xcconfig` in your build configuration (`NoteIt/Test.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `NoteIt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(production).xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(production).xcconfig` in your build configuration (`NoteIt/Production.xcconfig`).

[!] The `NoteIt [Debug (Development)]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (development).xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `NoteIt [Debug (Test)]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (test).xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `NoteIt [Debug (Production)]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (production).xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `NoteIt [Release(Development)]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(development).xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `NoteIt [Release(Test)]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(test).xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `NoteIt [Release(Production)]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release(production).xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

And I get the following error when I build after a clean:

[image]

My configurations settings looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you do a `pod update` after that? So it adds all the different files/configs to these new targets?

Comment: Don't I still just have one target, but different schemes?

Comment: Yes, but since each Scheme might have different lib path etc, they might not have the Pods settings, like the Framework Search Path, etc.

Comment: Do have a tutorial or blog post that introduces this? I'm kinda lost. The mentioned guide to not use pods

Comment: I've made the schemes shared by the way

Comment: Can you please share the your podfile please?

Comment: @umairhhhs done

Comment: @Recusiwe after changing the names for you Build configuration, try pod install, clean and then build. Let me know if its work for you or not.

Comment: @umairhhhs Done, I've added the output to my post.

Comment: Change the configuration file setting to None, then run pod install again.

The configuration file setting is found by selecting the project (not the target) and then the Info tab.

Comment: @umairhhhs I've added a ss to the post, should I change all of the configurations to none?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181911/discussion-between-umairhhhs-and-recusiwe).

Comment: have you try deleting `Podfile.lock` and reinstalling pods

Answer (score 10):

Delete the `.xcworkspace`, `Podfile.lock`and `Pods/` directory. Once Done do

```
pod install
```

Now, open the newly generated `.xcworkspace` file and add the `.xcconfig` path for Cocoapods in your own `.xcconfig` file.

For more details regarding solving this issue, you can refer to [link](https://hackernoon.com/a-cleaner-way-to-organize-your-ios-debug-development-and-release-distributions-6b5eb6a48356).
This would solve the problem.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: The link is not working.... could you please update it

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your issue and got the same error "sandbox not in sync with Podfile.lock"

Even after the .xcworkspace, Pod folders and Pod related phases got the same error, so taking a closer look on the error, I found out that it wasn't finding the Pods .xcconfig files. However, looking at the Pods folder, at the path `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt`, I saw that these files where indeed there:

```
> Pods-NoteIt.debug (beta) Pods-NoteIt.debug (development).xcconfig
> Pods-NoteIt.debug (production) Pods-NoteIt.debug (qa)
> Pods-NoteIt.debug (uat) Pods-NoteIt.debug
> 
> Pods-NoteIt.release (beta) Pods-NoteIt.release (development)
> Pods-NoteIt.release (production) Pods-NoteIt.release (qa)
> Pods-NoteIt.release (uat) Pods-NoteIt.release
> 
> Pods-NoteIt.debug (beta).xcconfig Pods-NoteIt.debug
> (development).xcconfig Pods-NoteIt.debug (production).xcconfig
> Pods-NoteIt.debug (qa).xcconfig Pods-NoteIt.debug (uat).xcconfig
> Pods-NoteIt.debug.xcconfig
> 
> Pods-NoteIt.release (beta).xcconfig Pods-NoteIt.release
> (development).xcconfig Pods-NoteIt.release (production).xcconfig
> Pods-NoteIt.release (qa).xcconfig Pods-NoteIt.release (uat).xcconfig
> Pods-NoteIt.release.xcconfig
```

What I did was to include the required files on each `.xcconfig` what I created manually. So for example, on the `Development.xcconfig` I added the following:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.debug (uat).xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-NoteIt/Pods-NoteIt.release (uat).xcconfig"
```

So your file would look liket this, if you added some other variables like the one in the tutorial:

[image]

After repeating this for each `.xcconfig` (Development, Production, QA, Beta, UAT) I was able to build and run the project succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

From another post, of syncing podfile.lock, the solution was:

```
pod deintegrate --verbose    
pod install --verbose
```

if that doesn't work, simply follow the error code and reinstall coca-pods
link to the question [The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738339/the-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I resolved it by deleting all pod files and  the derived data folder from my project. Uninstalled all pods from my machine. Then I reinstalled them.

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods

pod init

pod install

Answer (score -3):

in pod file, add target for each schema
Try something like this:

```
def shared_pods
pod 'SideMenuSwift'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'ObjectMapper'
pod 'SwiftDate'
pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults'
end
target 'Target1' do
shared_pods
end
target 'Target2' do
shared_pods
end
```

Comment: So the 'Target x" should be replaced by my shemas? They're development, test and release

Comment: Yes, try and tell me what happened.

Comment: But I want to share all my pods, so should I put them all the shared_pods?

Comment: It tells me it is unable to find targets, when I run pod install