# Error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, sandbox

I tried all commands and process mentioned in the links below -

[Error:"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock..." after installing RestKit with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res)

[the-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738339/the-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-ios/35446801)

Nothing worked for me. **Please help**

Comment: Move elsewhere the Podfile.lock (keep a copy though), redo a `pod install`.

Comment: Tried not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738339/the-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps: - delete Podfile, Pods and xcworkspace file and then run the command "pod install". Clean Xcode and then run your app.