# Flutter iOS build : 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I'm trying to do an iOS build of my flutter app.
It was originally developed as a web app, and that and the Android version build just fine.

I've needed to init the Podfile, and also [add some variable to fix a "Sandbox is not in sync" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107769/1290746).

Now I am facing the following error:

> my-app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9:
> 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h' file not found
>
> Failed to emit precompiled header
> '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bcjlnasdfassdfsdf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_1LNASLDFKSJDFRW-clang_10GAW6SLDFKJPY.pch'
> for bridging header
> '/Users/me/my-app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

If I open the **Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h** file, these are the contents:

```
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
```

And there is indeed no file called "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h" anywhere in my project.

Where do I get the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h file from?
How do I fix this issue?

---

#### Update :

I am also seeing this error :

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
>
> It appears that your application still contains the default signing
> identifier. Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
> open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
>
> Error launching application on iPhone.

---

#### Update :

Changing the signing ID results in the following :

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Swift
> Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant' in
> scope /Users/me/my-app/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:9:4

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include the Runner-Bridging-Header.h file in the "Objective-C Bridging Header" section in your project file in XCode as described here

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24869#issuecomment-461865955

Answer (score 1):

add `#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"`
to Runner-Bridging-Header.h file

Answer (score 0):

`GeneratedPluginRegistrant` is generated automaticlly by flutter.
I think you can do:

1. clean the build folder of ios project
2. `flutter pub upgrade` in flutter project
3. `pod update` in ios folder (If you have some plugin)
   Then try again.

Comment: Running this I do get the file "./example/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h" .. I've just updated the question to add more of the error message I was getting - something I previously thought was a red herring, but now makes more sense -- I'm going to look up adjusting the "signing id" now -- but please see my update to the question and let me know if you have more information.

Comment: I think it has told you the solution:Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode

Comment: Use your own sign id,you can debug on the real device

Comment: Sorry - I should have updated the question with the result of making that change - I have done so now - I'm leaving the other steps in the question because I still suspect there must be something fundamental wrong - everything I do raises a new issue - perhaps there is something wrong from the start of the process.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue did you find a solution?