# Cocoapods error for one project target while others are working fine

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, cocoapods, podspec

I have create 3 project target (Development, Production and Staging).Expect Production other working fine after pull the changes of others while building the production target xcode giving the error :
[image]

gone through some of the available solution but no success!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change something the conflict will be occur, do like remove your `WorkSpace` once and again install or update your `Pods`,it will Work

> Run `pod   install` or `pod update` your CocoaPods installation.

For additional Information see [this1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072396/cocoapods-errors-on-project-build)

**Choice-2**

> there's a problem with Cocoapods in your project.  Sometimes cocoapods can get out of sync and you need to re-initiate cocoapods. You should be able to resolve this error by:

- Deleting the Podfile.lock file in your project folder
- Deleting the Pods folder in your project folder
- Execute `pod install` in your project folder
- Do a `Clean` in Xcode
- Rebuild your project

> Conclusion: don't run pod install while project opened in the Xcode.

**Update answer**

**I. Project Cleanup**

1. In the project navigator, select your project
2. Select your target
3. Remove all libPods*.a in **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

**II. Update CocoaPods**

1. Launch Terminal and go to your project directory.
2. Update CocoaPods using the command `pod install`

Comment: i had removed the workspace and install the pod again but error still there.

Comment: let me try with Choice-2.

Comment: No Success :( Warning : The file “Pods-xxx.debug.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Comment: try removing check Pods Manifest.lock, Embed Pods Frameworks,Copy Pods resources from Build Phases and then reinstall the pod

Comment: @Pushpa -- I think you were opened your xcode and then tried, check this once https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2627

Comment: After closing the project i had run the pod install command. don't know whats wrong with only 1 target.

Comment: i am not getting why only one target is not building while other working fine.As i select the production target for clean and build xcode immediately show the 3 error(the above error snap shot).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Do you have any solution for "PhaseScriptExecution Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-fhsgyaibdsdyzpcasdrozshwswer/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.build/Script-BFF0B653743BE22530FAAADF.sh : line 2: /dev/nulldiff: Permission denied
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation. ??
I had deleted the derived data but not resolved this.

Comment: @Pushpa -- check the updated answer, and see this once also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i gone through this link and tried but not solved. let me try one more time.

Comment: @Pushpa -- good, if you are not solve the issue send your project to my mail ID , i will fix ur issue

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you for your such great Help!! but i can't.

Comment: @Pushpa -- not like some time it happens, if we move on step by step we can fix easily. so dont worry, any way if my answer is useful give the tick mark it wil useful for future user

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by this way :

After implementing lot many solution i got this error :
[image]

By removing **Check pods manifest.lock**, **Copy pods resources** and **Embed pods frameworks** from **Build Phases** of Tests project target(xxxTests) i solved the issue.

NOTE: If any one still getting any issue related to pods, then try to remove **libpods-xxx.a** from Link Binary with libraries and again add it.